# /etc/profile returns error: permission denied

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

In terminal I performed:

```
/etc/profile
```

Thus returns **permission denied.**

This surprised me as I had run the `sudo -s` command and my command prompt started with `root@...`

What's the reason for this?

Comment: This question is not version-specific, so should not be closed imho, but please consider upgrading to a supported release. We do not support EoL versions of Ubuntu here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default permissions of `/etc/profile` are

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 575 Okt 22  2015 /etc/profile
```

This means that the file is readable with commands like

```
cat /etc/profile
```

but not executable like

```
/etc/profile
```

as you tried to do (executing it). Because the executable permissions bit is not set, even with superuser permission this will fail and create the "Permission denied" message. As mentioned in the comments, it generally is no good idea to change the permissions in `/etc` because of security concerns, so if you really need to execute it, use the `source` command like this:

```
source /etc/profile
```

Comment: Agree with @guntbert, and you should explain in your answer that there is no reason to execute `/etc/profile` with the command `/etc/profile`. Presumably OP wanted to read the file, but if they wanted to *execute the file in the current shell* (which is reasonable, as it is a configuration file for shells), that would be done with the `source` command, and permissions will not be a problem - you are allowed to `source` files you can read, and that executes them in the current shell. `source` is therefore a pretty dangerous command - make sure you know what is in the file before you source it!

Answer (score 5):

It is because by default that file doesn't have any executable bits set. Even root cannot execute a file that is not executable for any user.

```
ls -l /etc/profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1722 Jan  6 20:09 /etc/profile
```

`/etc/profile` is there to be sourced at login, and sets the environment. Do `less /etc/profile` and you will see exactly what it sets.

By default, most of the regular files in `/etc` have permissions `644` which in symbolic notation is `rw-r--r--` and means the file owner can read and write to it, members of the group can only read the file, and others (any user or program) can only read the file.